# Android: AlertDialog - User click somewhere else

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an `Alert-dialog` with 2 buttons( Yes/No )
If user click `yes` or `no` the alert dialog behave normal and get into on-click method, but if user click or touch somewhere outside of alert dialog it just disappear, and nothing will happen, Is there any way to prevent dialog from disappearing when user clicked somewhere else???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prevent dismiss dialog box on outside touch use this

```
 dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: @HamidReza Your wel come. Glad to help you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your `AlertDialog`..

```
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

For more read here [Dialog cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 2):

You must give this line.

```
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

on bottom of the your  AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Use

```
YourAlertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

also you can use given below line for a practice that alert dialog  can only go away by pressing the buttons

```
 alertDialog.setCancelable(false).
```

This will make it so it can only go away by pressing the buttons.

Comment: what is the difference between setCanceledOnTouchOutside and setCancelable???

Comment: setCanceledOnTouchOutside only prevents dismissing by clicking outside of the dialog. But you can still dismiss it with back button for instance but after using alertDialog.setCancelable(false).  you need to choose one of the options from dialog

Comment: so I use both of them, thanks for your help @Jitesh

Comment: That is great , please raise it that it will be helpful for others as well!!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the combination of:

```
alertDialog.setCancelable(false); 
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```