# How to disable all other actions for an AlertDialog in Android?

Tags: android

I want my application to run only when GPS is turned on, and here's what I have for it in my activity so far.

```
private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    checkForGPS();
}

private void checkForGPS(){
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.gps_error_title));
    alertDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.gps_error_message));
    alertDialog.setButton(getResources().getString(R.string.alert_button_turn_on), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
        }
    });
    if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    checkForGPS();
}
```

Now i'm having issues with this dialog, because it works properly, but i am able to press my back button and just ignore it. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627663/android-alertdialog-user-click-somewhere-else/22627698#22627698

Comment: what do you mean by `because it works properly, but i am able to press my back button and just ignore it.`?

Comment: @Setu i meant that it does what it has to do, with it's buttons)

Comment: So what else do you want it to do? close the dialog on back press? not close the dialog on back press? only dismiss the dialog on button press?

Comment: @Setu i wanted it NOT to close when the button is pressed, i'm just new to android, didn't know how to do that. The reply below solved my problem, thank you for response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the dialog to be uncancellable.

```
alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

That way it's only closable with a command dismiss();

You can do that with setting your shown dialog and then calling the above command like this:

```
Dialog popup = alertDialog.show();
```

and later

```
popup.dismiss();
```

Also you will need to take care of the dialog when the screen rotates as it will disappear. The best option would be to save a boolean inside of your `onSaveInstanceState` and then check that state inside of `onCreate`.

Comment: @Carmine added some extra info. Select the answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: @Carmine there is a chance that your alertDialogue is still dismissable on clicking outside the alert. `alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`. Use this to fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

Either you can set the Alert as not cancellable:

```
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); //This must be there. To avoid the alert getting dismissed on clicking outside the alert.
alertDialog.setCancelable(false); //This is optional if you are going for the next option. I would say in your case YOU SHOULDN'T DO THIS. I will explain why.
```

Or you can override the back button action in the alertDialogue and `finish()` the activity.

```
alertDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            finish();
        }
        return true;
     }
 });
```

Let me throw a little light on why I did the second option. As per your question, the button in the AlertDialogue starts an Activity to prompt user to turn on GPS. When we write this line:

```
alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

It actually disables the back button. But then, how will the user exit the app? The back button will be disabled and there is no way to exit the app(there is no button on the alert to exit and the back button is disabled). So there should be some way for the user to exit the application without having to use the home button and all. I hope you understood my point.

Comment: @Downvoter, do leave a comment when you downvote. What is the problem with this one?

Comment: Bad idea to override onBackPressed. Also why override it if setCancelable prevents the back key from functioning?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I actually meant to override the back button. But I did it in the wrong place. See my edit above. I have explained why I did it. :)

Comment: +1 for overriding the back button and allowing user to exit app. This should be the accepted answer. Why down vote on this?